# Getting the mimetypes of files loaded in a UIWebView

Tags: iphone, ios4, uiwebview, download, mime-types

I am trying to get the MIME Types of files loaded in a UIWebView so that I can download them the method i have right now works some of the times, is there anyway I can do it better?

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView*)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest*)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType 
{   
   NSURL *url = request.URL;
   NSString *main = url.absoluteString;
   //enter code here currentURL = main;
   NSURLRequest *req  = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
   NSURLConnection *conn = [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:req delegate:self];
   [conn start];
   return YES;
}

NSString *mime = [response MIMEType];
NSLog(@"%@",mime);
DownloadManagerAppDelegate *delegate = (DownloadManagerAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

DLMan *downloadView = [[DLMan alloc] init];
if ([mime rangeOfString:@"application/x-compressed"].length>0 || [mime rangeOfString:@"application/x-zip-compressed"].length>0  || [mime rangeOfString:@"application/zip"].length>0 || [mime rangeOfString:@"multipart/x-zip"].length>0) 
{
  self.tabBarController.selectedIndex = 1;
  [[delegate myDownloadManager]addDownload:currentURL];
  NSLog(currentURL);
  NSLog(@"download");
}
```

Answer (score 3):

In the `NSURLConnection`delegate `didReceiveResponse` use something like this:

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response 
{
   NSString *mime = [response MIMEType];
}
```

---

As I have read that you're not getting The MIME correctly you might be interested in another approach, create a `plist` of the MIME Types for example **mimeTypes.plist**

*(Not necessarily all the types at least the types you are going to work with or handle)*

Load them into a `NSDicionary` using:

```
NSString *mainBundlePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath];
NSString *plistPath = [mainBundlePath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"mimeTypes.plist"];

NSDictionary *dict = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:plistPath]
```

Check the MIME by searching the Target's Extension:

```
[dict valueForKey:@"mp3"];  // will return audio/mpeg.
```

Please check this link for the list of [MIME Types](http://www.w3schools.com/media/media_mimeref.asp).

Comment: I have tried your first example, and your second one wont work because I am trying to download from filehosts and they sometimes include .zip or .mp3 in the url before you can download it